# Toggle button like google places

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can we implement Toggle button like google places
When click on write Review we smile images and sad images

http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=7069125495329769622&hl=en-IN

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, when click on "Write Review" it focus on the review textarea? I would use jquery (see http://api.jquery.com/click/), if you want an easy solution, on the postback just focus on the textbox...